# Link boost with cmake and visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015, cmake

When i try to link with boost using cmake to generate visual studio 2015 files, cmake generates a library-path like this:

```
optimized;D:/work/libs/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0/boost_regex-vc140-mt-1_63.lib;debug;D:/work/libs/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0/boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib;[...]
```

But visual studio tries to link `libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib` with the solution file generated from the cmake file, which uses this path.

The relevant part of the cmake file:

```
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} [...] BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
message("${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The `optimized` and `debug` paths above are from the `message(...)` command here and the visual studio output is

```
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib'
```

Which is correct, as it should use `boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib`, which is a absolute path in `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`.

The strange think is, when is use `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` before `find_package`, the problem is exactly the other way round, cmake finds the `libboost_` files, while VS expects the `boost_` files.

Comment: `libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib` corresponds to the static version of boost::regex, from which I guess that CMake wants to link the static library. Can you try, in your CMakeLists, to add `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::dynamic_linking)`, or to have `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)` before your `find_package(Boost))` ?

Comment: I added both and it doesn't change the error. I think when it works as expected, ``$Boost_LIBRARIES`` should contain the ``libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib`` file as absolute path, shouldn't it?

Comment: You can also have a look what the Visual Studio solution wants to link from the project properties, there at least it should be given as an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the main problem was, that another library which i am linking into my library was linked statically against boost.

When i linked my project dynamically with boost, this worked, but linking the other library now did not find the needed static version, as the main project did not include the static versions into its path (which is the correct behaviour for my project), while the linked library seems not to include the symbols linked statically from boost, but just to reference them for later linking in some way.

At the moment its working by making sure, that all parts are linking against static or dynamic versions without mixing.

It would probably work with having both in the path, but i guess then it will get confusing which library is used for which function.